# Django Template Variables to Javascript File

Tags: javascript, django, typescript, django-templates

Currently I have my Django project set up so that the JS variables that depend on template variables are first defined under a script tag in the HTML template. Then, when the template runs, the JS variable gets created and added to the Javascript context, causing other external JS scripts to be able to use said variable without declaring it anywhere.

*Html template:*

```html
<body>
   content
</body>

<script>
   const var = "{{ my_template_var }}";
</script>
<script type="module" src="{% url 'app_name/index.js' %}"></script>
```

*JS Script (app_name/index.js)*

```js
console.log(var)       // Prints value of "my_template_var" in the form of a string
```

However, I dont like the fact that the `var` variable in the JS script just "magically" has the value defined in the template when it runs (there's no actual statement saying `const var = something`). Is there any way that I can include a declaration in my JS file (not a comment) so that its a bit clearer to the rest of the developers from where the variable is coming from?

(NOTE: I'm mainly doing this as well because when using Typescript, those variables appear as undefined, even though they are receiving a value from somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found I could do this is by using the `declare` statement on the Typescript file. So variables that received their value from another script tag:

```html
<!-- Index.html -->
<script>
   variable = 5
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I can just do:

```js
// script.ts that compiles into script.js
declare const variable: type;
```